# Wordpress SideBar area not Appearing

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, sidebar

I want to place an advert on the side bar, but the widget area appears in the wp-admin panel(appearance>widgets)

However, when I place my ad in the Side bar widget area, it does not appear on the site.

I used the code below to create the widget area and placed it in fuctions.php file of my theme. Where am I going wrong?

```
     if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {  
     register_sidebar(array(  
      'name' => 'Sidebar Widgets',  
      'id'   => 'sidebar-widgets',  
      'description'   => 'Widget Area',  
      'before_widget' => '<div id="one" class="two">',  
      'after_widget'  => '</div>',  
      'before_title'  => '<h2>',  
      'after_title'   => '</h2>'  
     ));  
    }
```

I'll be grateful.

Below is my page template.

```
<?php
/**
The template for displaying all pages.
*/

get_header(); 

?>

<div id="main" class="<?php echo $solid_content_class; ?> clearfix" role="main">
<?php 

do_action('solid_before_content'); 

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

get_template_part( 'lib/content/content', 'page' ); 

endwhile; // end of the loop.

do_action('solid_after_content'); 

// If the theme supports comments in pages and comments are open or we have at least 
one comment, load up the comment template
if( solid_theme_supports( 'comments', 'pages' ) && ( comments_open() || '0' != 
get_comments_number() )  ) comments_template( '', true ); 

?>
</div><!-- #main -->

<?php if( $solid_sidebar_location === 'left' || $solid_sidebar_location === 'right' ) 
{ ?>

<aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar <?php echo $solid_sidebar_class; ?>">
    <div id="sidebar-main" class="sidebar">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div><!--sidebar-main-->
</aside>

<?php }

get_footer(); ?>'
```

Comment: calling the  sidebar in page  like dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-widget' );

Comment: What does your page template look like? Are you sure you're calling the sidebar?

Comment: @mevius , Thanks for your comment. Please check the page template I have added above.

Answer (score 0):

```
function debatingday_widgets_init() 
{
    // Primary Widget area (left, fixed sidebar)
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Primary Widget Area', 'debatingday' ),
        'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
        'description' => __( 'Here you can put one or two of your main widgets (like an intro text, your page navigation or some social site links) in your left sidebar. The sidebar is fixed, so the widgets content will always be visible, even when scrolling down the page.', 'debatingday' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="s-widget" id="%1$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h5><i class="fa fa-folder-open color"></i> ',
        'after_title' => '</h5>',
    ) );


    // Secondary Widget area (right, additional sidebar)
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Secondary Widget Area', 'debatingday' ),
        'id' => 'secondary-widget-area',
        'description' => __( 'Here you can put all the additional widgets for your right sidebar.', 'debatingday' ),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
/* Register sidebars by running debatingday_widgets_init() on the widgets_init hook. */
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'debatingday_widgets_init' );
```